# Merging pdfs using Pdfcopy

Tags: java

I'm using the Pdfcopy to merge multiple Pdfs. But, the fields in the generated pdf shows empty and on clicking it shows the value.

Comment: Please share example source and target PDFs for analysis.

Comment: This may work well on full PDF viewers but may fail on some previewers.

Comment: This is probably due to missing appearances of those fields. Share the PDF as MKL suggested...